# Unity NullPointerException when trying to access a LobbyPlayer instance in a NetworkLobby

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a network game for Android using Unity 5.1.4 and c# . First I made a network game that can be hosted and joined to. For causes of team management I need a lobby that first needs the clients to establish a connection to the server to synchronize variables.

I used the Unity Standard Assets and tried to derive some methods for the necessary scripts. Still there are some issues to get the NetworkLobby attached to the working network game.

More precisely I need this lobby to let a joined player chose a "team" and by that which player prefab to get spawned.

The Situation/ Idea:

There are two main scripts that are running. A NetworkLobbyManager_custom that extends the NetworkLobbyManager and a LobbyPlayer_custom that extends the LobbyPlayer. Both are the standard assets for a Lobby. The NetworkLobbyManager is atached to a GameObject and the LobbyPlayer_custom is attached to a prefab that I use as lobby prefab.

The NetworkLobbyManger_Custom manages the Canvases and Buttons within my menu and lobby scenes. It also etablishes a connection between server an clients.

The LobbyPlayer_custom is there to save the team the player chose and to change to the game scene on the client.

The App works like this:

1. the NetworklobbyManager_custom lets you start a host/ join as client.
2. after you estalished a connection a canvas with two buttons to choose the team pops up.
3. when a button is clicked the team is checked for free slots and the chosen team should be saved in the LobbyPlayer_custom script.

This is where I have a problem. I can't get acces to the LobbyPlayerPrefabs that contain the scripts or the scripts to save the choice.

When I try to get access to the LobbyPlayer_custom script to find the id of the LobbyPlayer_custom that made the choice, I get a NullPointerException.

```
    private string GetLobbyPlayersIdByIp (string ip)
    {
      LobbyPlayer_custom lobbyPlayer;
        for(int i=0; i< maxPlayers; i++)
        {
            if ((lobbySlots[i] != null))
            {   // nullpointer here
                lobbyPlayer = lobbySlots[i] as LobbyPlayer_custom;
                if (lobbyPlayer.GetPlayerIP().Equals(ip))
                {
                    return lobbyPlayer.GetPlayerUID();
                }
            }
        }
        return "null";
    }
```

I also tried to get access to the LobbyPlayer_custom script through finding all LobbyPlayerPrefab instances by something like this:

```
    LobbyPlayer_custom lobbyPlayer;
        Object[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(GameObject));

        foreach (Object obj in objs)
        {
            if (obj.name.Contains("player") || obj.name.Contains("Player"))
            {
                lobbyPlayer = (obj as GameObject).GetComponent<LobbyPlayer_custom>();
                //none of the lobbyPlayers methods are accessible
            }          
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea how access all the LobbyPlayer scripts of the spawned Prefabs?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're instantiating the prefabs, FindObjectsOfType() should get you what you need. Another option is to store each script instance in a list when the prefab is instantiated.